# Valgrind error in C++ 3D array

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm having troubles understanding a Valgrind error displayed compiling a C++ program to create and manage a 3D array.

I coded the software on my Mac, and everything looked fine, but when I ported it to Ubuntu not only I get the Valgrind error, the output is also different (and wrong) from the one in Mac.

Here is the Valgrind error:

```
==10705== Invalid write of size 4
==10705==    at 0x401095: Matrice3D<int>::Matrice3D(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int const&) (in /media/psf/sharedFolder/Progetto_2/main.exe)
==10705==    by 0x400BE1: main (in /media/psf/sharedFolder/Progetto_2/main.exe)
==10705==  Address 0x5ab6e10 is 0 bytes after a block of size 192 alloc'd
==10705==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10705==    by 0x40102E: Matrice3D<int>::Matrice3D(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int const&) (in /media/psf/sharedFolder/Progetto_2/main.exe)
==10705==    by 0x400BE1: main (in /media/psf/sharedFolder/Progetto_2/main.exe)
==10705== 
--10705-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--10705-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x1105AB6E38;  sp: 0x802ca9e30
```

and the constructor referred:

```
Matrice3D(unsigned int height, unsigned int width, unsigned int depth, const T &value) : _3D_matrix(0), _height(0), _width(0), _depth(0) { 

    try {
       _3D_matrix = new T[height * width * depth];
            for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++) {
                        _3D_matrix[j * height * depth + k * depth + z] = value; 
                    }
                }
            }
   }
    catch(...) {
        delete[] _3D_matrix;
        throw;
    }


    _height = height;
    _width = width;
    _depth = depth;

    }
```

Anyone had a similar experience? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not using `std::vector` for the underlying storage. That's wrong.

Comment: The `catch` thing is just wrongheaded.

Comment: This 3-level loop could be simplified to `for(size_t i{}; (height * width * depth) != i; ++i) { _3D_matrix[i] = value; }` Existing indexing seems to be strange.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf unfortunately I can't use std::vector or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index calculation is wrong.

`z` goes from `0` to `depth`.
`j` goes from `0` to `height`.
`k` goes from `0` to `width`.

So far so good (well, `j` and `k` instead of `x` and `y` are unusual and probably a good part of the confusion). But:

```
_3D_matrix[j * height * depth + k * depth + z] = value;
```

Multiplying `j` by `height` is the mistake, it should probably be `width`.
Consider this case: `j = height - 1`, `k = 0`, `z = 0`. Then your index would be `height * depth * (height - 1)`, which is obviously incorrect if `height` is different from `width`.

A trick for debugging such cases where you are unsure about array indices is to consider the extreme cases. If you think about the above case (or the case that all loop variables are maximal) you will immediately see that your index can exceed your array size.

Comment: thanks a lot! changing `height` to `width` solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem with write is caused by mixing up ranges/indexing of various `for` levels:

```
_3D_matrix[j * height * depth + k * depth + z] = value;
```

Take a look here: https://ideone.com/gkUXib - your code moved into a standalone function with added index output. The output shows some indexes are assigned to twice (i.e. 22 in the example), some are left never assigned to (like 63). Order of the indexes looks weird, making it hard to reason about.

Possibly some combination of width, height and depth may cause an error like you've noticed.

I'd recommend simplifying the fors variables (make a "row" mean a row, not something else), use a `std::array` or simply use a single dimension array and implement rows, columns and depth yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot for the ideone link, it helped me realizing what the problem is. I coded those 3 nested loops based on a sketch I made on paper, thinking it would have worked. I'm now gonna try to fix it!